# Loss of atmosphere to a vacuum

Tags: pressure, vacuum

I'm working to craft a space-horror themed [RPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-playing_game) a la Dungeons & Dragons and I've run into a situation I can't resolve on my own.

At what rate is atmosphere lost to space through various sized apertures? I'm looking generally at these sizes(in diameter) 10' 5' 30" 15" 7" 3" 1"

Trying to determine how quickly the cabins/holds/etc will decompress. It is the deep space version of falling rocks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate [this here](http://www.tlv.com/global/TI/calculator/air-flow-rate-through-orifice.html)

Remember that a vacuum has a pressure of 0 ABSOLUTE! while atmospheric pressure is 0 GAUGE pressure or 1 atm absolute.

Also useful are these [flow rate meters](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/orifice-nozzle-venturi-d_590.html)

So, roughly...

$$10' \rightarrow 2.4*10^6 SCFM$$
$$5' \rightarrow 600000 SCFM$$
$$30" \rightarrow 158000 SCFM$$
$$15" \rightarrow 38000 SCFM$$
$$7" \rightarrow 8000 SCFM$$
$$3" \rightarrow 1500 SCFM$$
$$1" \rightarrow 170 SCFM$$

Comment: Note that space is *not* a vacuum. There's roughly 1 hydrogen atom per cubic centimeter which translates to a pressure of about $10^{-11}\,{\rm dyne/cm}^2\sim10^{-15}\,{\rm mmHg}$

Comment: That is true but, for his purposes, insignificant. The point is that the international spacestation worth of air would be drained through a 7" hole in less than a minute (if the pressure on the interior was still roughly 1 bar the whole time. Obviously it would slow as the pressure decreases in the cabin.)